# Inner components of a recursive type are not copied in intrinsic assignment

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Consider the following Fortran program:

```
program test_prg
  implicit none

  type :: recursive_block
    type(recursive_block), allocatable :: subblocks(:, :)
  end type

  type(recursive_block) :: top_level
  top_level = init_recursive()
  print *, loc(top_level % subblocks(1, 1) % subblocks)
  deallocate(top_level % subblocks)

contains

  function init_recursive() result(res)
    type(recursive_block) :: res
    type(recursive_block), allocatable :: inner(:, :)

    allocate(inner(1, 1))
    allocate(inner(1, 1) % subblocks(1, 1))
    print *, loc(inner(1, 1) % subblocks)
    res % subblocks = inner
  end function
end program
```

Compiled with gfortran 10.2, this code crashes on `deallocate(top_level % subblocks)` with the following message:

```
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
```

I suspect this might have something to do with the fact that both print statements print the same number, i.e. the address of `top_level % subblocks(1, 1) % subblocks` matches that of `inner(1, 1) % subblocks`, which is a component of a local variable and is supposed to be deallocated on exit from the function.

Is this a gfortran bug?

Comment: Does it matter at all, provided that `inner` is not used and is just automatically deallocated on the next line? Do you have an example where it would matter? It appears to be a nice optimization.

Comment: @VladimirF The local variable will be deallocated on procedure exit, so this address would be invalid in the calling code. I've expanded the example to showcase it.

Comment: Only  now I realized you have a recursive allocatable type. Those are new in Fortran 2008 and surely much less tested (see [PR45516](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45516)). There could be some bug there. I am not getting any crash but I do get some invalid reads from valgrind.